# Conditionally compiled NSLog alternative in framework class for use outside of framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, ios4, nslog

I have an NSLog alternative that outputs the class it's called from as well as the line number and method (selector) called PLog in a class called PLogging. It's the exact same as the DLog taken from [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog) with the exception of the name change. The advantage of `DLog` as it is written is that when compiled under Release mode, the log call is changed to a comment, negating the performance impact you would otherwise be subject to. I want to be able to use this and keep it within the framework, but be able to call it from the projects I add the framework to. But still have the log calls compiled to comments when in Release mode. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a white list approach: add a preprocessor definition to your debug configurations which enables DLog/Plog to log to the console. In every other case it turns to comments.

Please have a look at [this blog post](http://www.evilexperiments.com/evilog/?p=7) which seems to point a finger at your problem. Of course, assuming that you don't want to change the way you are achieving your functionality: macros. I'm quoting abit: "An example of the basic problem is you want to link to a library that has both a Debug and a Release version.  So in your application you want your Debug version to link to the Debug version of the library, and you want your Release version to link the Release version of the library."

I would rather tend to use targets for that, the trouble does look uncomfortable.

Comment: Right. I've got that right now, but it only works within the framework. So once the framework is compiled, is there any way to have the framework rely on a preprocessor definition of the project in which it's included?

Comment: I see the problem. If you build your module as a framework, it has already been precompiled, so you cannot use this method to switch the logging on/off. Macros won't work in this case. If you depend on this mechanism, you could build two versions of your framework: debug on and off and link to the one you need in your project depending on a define.

Comment: Can you think of any other solution? I think it would be annoying to have to remember to switch out the framework when releasing. Something more automated, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, been ill for a few days. Well that can be achieved quite easily: You can use two targets and put the needed framework under linked libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Third-party frameworks aren't allowed by the App Store.  I assume you've got a static library or source files that you add to your apps with a cross-project reference?

If you've set your library project up with a debug flag set for your Debug configuration and unset for your Release configuration, then all you have to do is use the same configuration names for your app project, and the library will be built with the same configuration.

Comment: I have set up a static library for both iPhone and Simulator that get built into a single *.framework. Your answer _would_ work, but it doesn't help me beyond what I had before. I was hoping that when I built my project in Release mode, then the PLog statements would be compiled into comments. Right now I've got it switching based upon a processor definition.